# Can I choose what language or software to install with the 12.04 DVD?

Tags: installation, language-support

I was wondering is it possible to choose what language or software to install with ubuntu 12.04 DVD, when we're installing it ?

Answer (score 1):

The default Setup CDs use the language you select in the setup dialog. After installation you can add or remove whatever you need (including language packs).
If you use an alternative Setup CD you should be able to customize the installation much more during setup but i don't remember if you can go down to individual package selection with these as well. At least you can select groups of packages like LAMP and so on.